# Message passing from extension to background page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, message-passing

I'm trying to create a page action extension in chrome. I have an html page corresponding to the popup that gets displayed on clicking the page action. I have included a script file `popup.js` in this html page. From this page I'm trying to send a message to a background js file `background.js`. The problem is that I'm calling `sendRequest` only once from `popup.js` but I'm receiving it in the background page multiple times. I'm doing a file action there which results in script errors because of concurrent access. I'm pasting the code related to message passing here

**extension file - popup.js**

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({"intent" : "read"}, function (message) {
      console.log(message);
});
```

**background page - background.js**

```
(function(){
var fileName = "credentials.txt";
var fileSystem;

function checkUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(/https?:\/\/.*?\/olc/.test(tab.url)) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
        chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function (request, sender, callback) {
            callback("printed");
        });
    }
}
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkUrl);
})();
```

The listener is called 4 times in this case. The callback will be called the first time. The next 3 times it gives an error saying `Could not send response: Cannot send a response more than once per chrome.extension.onRequest listener per document (message was sent by extension kaejjpmlibijbgbgcfodphlkcjjkmjlk).` Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

They're supposed to work only once.

You can either use the long-lived messaging system or reattach the same handler over and over again upon receiving the message from the content script.

Answer (score 0):

Use chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage(). You will have access to background page from yor popup.
Or write to localStorage and use listener.

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function (e) {}, false);
```

You will have problems with memory leak if you will use chrome.extension.sendRequest for comunication between popup and background.html.